# entity_metadata_Wrapper and entity_create create a node for every field of the content type

Tags: 7, nodes, database

There is a table with two columns `title`,`body_value`. I need to create a node for each row of this table. Table name is `french`. This is my code

```
$query = db_select('french', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('title','body_value'))
      ->range(11,5)
      ->execute();

foreach($query as $item) {
    print "Row"."<br/>";
    $title = $item->title;
    $body = $item->body_value;
    $values = array(
        'type' => 'article',
        'uid' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
        'comment' => 0,
        'promote' => 0,
        'language'  => 'fr'
    );
    $entity = entity_create ('node', $values);
    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $ewrapper->title->set($title);      
    $ewrapper->field_body->set(array('value' => $body,'format'=>'full_html'));
    $ewrapper->save();
}
```

The problem is, after running this code 10 contents are created the five contents are repeated twice.

But when I run this code

```
foreach($query as $item) {
    print "Row"."<br/>";
    $title = $item->title;
    $body = $item->body_value;
    $values = array(
        'type' => 'article',
        'uid' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
        'comment' => 0,
        'promote' => 0,
        'language'  => 'fr'
    );
    $entity = entity_create ('node', $values);
    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $ewrapper->title->set($title);      
    //$ewrapper->field_body->set(array('value' => $body,'format'=>'full_html'));
    $ewrapper->save();
}
```

no duplicate content is created. Why this code creates a node for each column of the `french` table?

Thanks.